# Excel checkifs for 2 different tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In my worksheet 1 checkif checks how many times a person appears that month at work. Sometimes, certain days are counted double but unfortunately I don't know how to create a checkifs that will count the additional days for certain people.
`=checkifs(F3:I64;P3;J3:M64;S1)` is the code I'm using. I also tried `=checkif(AND(checkif($F$3:$I$62;P2);checkif($J$3:$J$64;2)))`. [image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: Please show a reduced example with what you have in each cell and what you are trying to do. I suspect this can be solved with `SUMPRODUCT`, but it is difficult to parse what you're after.

Comment: Ok. Let me rephrase:
Let's take "Zar". That persoon appears 8 times in the month. BUT on the 8th and on the 11th she receives double the payment. At the top right I have the "COUNTIF" for single payments. My goal is that the amount of days + the double payments (so "Zar" should be paid as for 10 days, not 8). I tried the below  code and didn't get what I needed. (These are actresses, and there are 4 columns because sme of them play different roles n different days)

Comment: Please post your sample data in an editable format with desired output, that help us to test or suggested answer. Also don't provide new information in comments,  but edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following formula (place where suitable. This is for column F and the name in P3; add for the rest and drag for the rest of names):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($F$3:$F$64=P3);$J$3:$J$64)
```

Then, I'd rephrase as well. In order to compute for names in columns F to I, the formula for the name in P3 would be (checked, it works ok, just translate function name SUMPRODUCT to your locale):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($F$3:$F$64=P3);$J$3:$J$64)+SUMPRODUCT(--($G$3:$G$64=P3);$J$3:$J$64)+SUMPRODUCT(--($H$3:$H$64=P3);$J$3:$J$64)+SUMPRODUCT(--($I$3:$I$64=P3);$J$3:$J$64)
```

Please be careful for trailing or unwanted extra spaces in name cells, as this is required for the formulas to work. For the rest of actresses names, just drag down.

Kind regards.

Comment: Ok. Let me rephrase:
Let's take "Zar". That persoon appears 8 times in the month. BUT on the 8th and on the 11th she receives double the payment. At the top right I have the "COUNTIF" for single payments. My goal is that the amount of days + the double payments (so "Zar" should be paid as for 10 days, not 8). I tried the code and didn't get what I needed. I also tried to change it:`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($F$3:$I$64;P3);COUNTIF($J$3:$J$64;2))` (These are actresses, and there are 4 columns because sme of them play different roles n different days).

Comment: Precisel what I needed. Perfect and thank you :D.